# Razor/Syncfusion: On async page loading, treedata won't populate unless I make an action

Tags: c#, blazor, syncfusion

So I am writing this application in razor and right now I am doing a custom navigation bar. Now, the problem is in the `OnInitialized` event that I wrote:

```
 protected async override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        var user = (await AuthStat).User;
        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            await Authenticated();
        }
        else
        {
            await NotAuthenticated();
        }
    }
```

Where the functions are:

```
 protected Task Authenticated()
    {
        treedata = null;
        treedata = new List<TreeData>();
        treedata.Add(new TreeData { nodeId = "01", nodeText = "Acasa", iconCss = "icon-microchip icon" });
        treedata.Add(new TreeData { nodeId = "03", nodeText = "Logout", iconCss = "icon-thumbs-up-alt icon" });
        treedata.Add(new TreeData { nodeId = "04", nodeText = "Vremea", iconCss = "icon-th icon" });
        treedata.Add(new TreeData { nodeId = "05", nodeText = "Profil", iconCss = "icon-code icon" });
        treedata.Add(new TreeData { nodeId = "06", nodeText = "Calcul Salariu", iconCss = "icon-chrome icon" });
        treedata.Add(new TreeData { nodeId = "07", nodeText = "Mijloace Fixe", iconCss = "icon-up-hand icon" });
        return Task.CompletedTask;

    }

    protected Task NotAuthenticated()
    {
        treedata = null;
        treedata = new List<TreeData>();
        treedata.Add(new TreeData { nodeId = "01", nodeText = "Acasa", iconCss = "icon-microchip icon" });
        treedata.Add(new TreeData { nodeId = "02", nodeText = "Login", iconCss = "icon-docs icon" });
        treedata.Add(new TreeData { nodeId = "04", nodeText = "Vremea", iconCss = "icon-th icon" });
        treedata.Add(new TreeData { nodeId = "06", nodeText = "Calcul Salariu", iconCss = "icon-chrome icon" });
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

The variable `treedata` is:

```
SfTreeView<TreeData> TreeView;
   public class TreeData
   {
       public string nodeId { get; set; }
       public string nodeText { get; set; }
       public string iconCss { get; set; }
       public bool hasChild { get; set; }
       public string pid { get; set; }
   }
```

My problem is the following: Whenever the page loads, the treedata will populate only when an action occur (ie. search or toggle the navigation menu) and I want to show when the page load, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//protected async override void OnInitialized()
  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
    // base.OnInitialized();
    // ...  like before
```

An `async void` method is not (cannot be) awaited. Your Authenticated/NotAuthenticated methods run out of sync with the rendering.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that since I am a newbie in this domain. Furthermore, I will look more into documentation to understand it better!

Answer (score 1):

We have checked your attached code and found out that you have used await method for get the user name and TreeView datasource. This function takes some time to fetch the user name and datasource of TreeView component. TreeView component does not wait until the data fetched from that function, so it rendered using empty datasource. This is the cause of your reported issue.

We have already consider this problem as a feature support to be implemented in TreeView component. The support for this feature will be included in our **Volume 3 release** which is expected to be rolled out at the **end of September 2020.**

We appreciate  your patience.

Regards,
Sowmiya. P

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did managed to make it function by creating a viewmodel and then calling it on the page!